# Jolt- Based on the index need to iterate a list and form common object from the index

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have requirement of iterating a list which can have same tag name but different indexes like 0,1,2. So I need to iterate the list, take out the common indexes and from that index take out name and value tag and form as another list.

Request:

```json
{
  "characteristic": [
    {
      "name": "BucketName",
      "value": "testName0",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketName",
      "value": "testName1",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketName",
      "value": "testName2",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId0",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId1",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId2",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response Required:

```json
{
  "bucketList": [
    {
      "BucketName": "testName0",
      "BucketId": "testId0"
    },
    {
      "BucketName": "testName1",
      "BucketId": "testId1"
    },
    {
      "BucketName": "testName2",
      "BucketId": "testId2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How could we achieve this based on the index from alist?

When More elements are there how to handle this case to skip if values not coming and add only tags that are coming.
Example Request:

```json
{
  "characteristic": [
    {
      "name": "BucketName",
      "value": "testName0",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId0",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketType",
      "value": "testType1",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId1",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketName",
      "value": "testName2",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId2",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketId",
      "value": "testId3",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketName",
      "value": "testName3",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "BucketData",
      "value": "testData3",
      "@type": "bucketInfo",
      "arrayIndex": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response expected:

```json
{
    "bucketlist": [
        {
            "BucketName": "testName0",
            "BucketId": "testId0"
        },
        {
            "BucketType": "testType1",
            "BucketId": "testId1"
        },
        {
            "BucketName": "testName2",
            "BucketId": "testId2"
        },
        {
            "BucketName": "testName3",
            "BucketId": "testId3",
            "BucketData": "testData3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply two successive **shift** transformations. Take **"@(2,arrayIndex)"** as a common factor in order to combine the elements under the commonly tagged arrays in the first transformation, and then display them as desired within the second one such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "value": {
            "@(1,value)": "@(2,arrayIndex).@(2,name)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "bucketList[]"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick help. But when there are more elements like this and some are skipped, the values for new ones does not get added. always bucketId and bucketName comes for above spec.

Comment: I have edited question above @Barbaros

Comment: yes wanted dynamically @Barbaros

Comment: thanks @Barbaros for quick solution

Comment: you're welcome @Chethan , have a nice study